# Import Error while importing a Cython .pyx file

Tags: python, cython

I have a python file which imports multiple packages using the following code:

```
from pyzoltan.core.carray import UIntArray, DoubleArray
from pyzoltan.core import zoltan
```

The first two imports, i.e.`UIntArray` and `DoubleArray` are successfully imported but the third import i.e. `zoltan` gives `ImportError`.

The `pyzoltan/core` directory contains the following files:

```
|-- __init__.py
|-- __init__.pyc
|-- carray.pxd
|-- carray.pxd.mako
|-- carray.pyx
|-- carray.pyx.mako
|-- carray.so
|-- generator.py
|-- generator.pyc
|-- msstdint.h
|-- tests
|   |-- 3d_partition.py
|   |-- 3d_partition.pyc
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- __init__.pyc
|   |-- __pycache__
|   |   |-- test_zoltan.cpython-27-PYTEST.pyc
|   |-- geometric_partitioner.py
|   |-- geometric_partitioner.pyc
|   |-- mesh.txt
|   |-- test_zoltan.py
|   |-- test_zoltan.pyc
|   |-- zcomm.py
|   |-- zcomm.pyc
|-- zoltan.pxd
|-- zoltan.pyx
|-- zoltan_comm.pxd
|-- zoltan_comm.pyx
|-- zoltan_dd.pxd
|-- zoltan_dd.pyx
|-- zoltan_utils.py
|-- zoltan_utils.pyc
```

Is the problem due to the absence of `zoltan.mako` and `zoltan.so` or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You have `carray.so` but not `zoltan.so`.  Whatever build process produced the former should be able to produce the latter as well (i.e. by running `cython` on `zoltan.pyx` and `zoltan.pxd`).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the pyzoltan/core/zoltan.so file.

The `.pyx` file can be compiled by Cython to a `.c` file, which can be compiled by a `C` compiler to `.so` file (or `.pyd` file on Windows).

There are [a number of ways](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/quickstart/build.html) to build Cython code. The normal/recommended way is to write a distutils/setuptools `setup.py` file. The contents could look something like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize("zoltan.pyx")
)
```

and then you could build the `.so` file by running

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

---

But really you shouldn't need to write your own setup.py. If you install the [core dependencies](http://pysph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#dependencies) (and making sure they satisfy the version requirements) then follow the [installation instructions](http://pysph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#building-and-linking-pyzoltan-on-osx-linux) then you should have `zoltan` ready to go.

Comment: I was able to get zoltan.so compiled using a `setup.py` but now on running my python code, I get another import error saying `ImportError: /home/invinciblycool/Documents/SEM5/pdc_lab/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyzoltan/core/zoltan.so: undefined symbol: Zoltan_Set_Obj_List_Fn
` I know this might be very hard to figure out, but any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes,  I have already installed PySPH with pip, but a script which involves zoltan as a requirement is not working due to the same error while the core dependencies seem to work absolutely fine.

Comment: And pyzoltan is not a part of PySPH, please refer the installation instructions. `If you want to use PySPH in parallel, you will need mpi4py and the Zoltan data management library. PySPH will work in serial without mpi4py or Zoltan. Simple build instructions for Zoltan are included below.`

Comment: [The instructions](http://pysph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#building-and-linking-pyzoltan-on-osx-linux) refer to a build script: `./build_zoltan.sh INSTALL_PREFIX`. If you are running into problems running the build script, your question should show the output you receive after running this command.